# PHP AppEngine - CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Using PHP AppEngine I get an error when using extension=curl.so within PHP.ini. Using google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"  works fine.

Warning: curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set in /base/data/home/apps/s~ACCOUNT-1141/1.390397645927682479/includes/vendor/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client/src/Google/Spreadsheet/DefaultServiceRequest.php on line 241

This leads to an empty response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.